# Javascript RegEx Nested Object Key

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a preset object which has bunch of keys like this:

```
preset: {
  abc: { type: Boolean, optional: true},
  bcd: { type: Boolean, optional: true},
  def: { type: Boolean, optional: true},
  efg: { type: Boolean, optional: true},
}
```

I tried using regex like this:

```
regEx: {
  test: /abc|bcd|def|efg/,
}
```

Now I want to use it to test the keys of preset.
I tried to many different ways but eslint keeps giving me syntax error:

```
preset.[regEx.test]: { type: Boolean, optional: true}

[`preset.${regEx.test}`]: { type: Boolean, optional: true}
```

etc.

This is for db schema, if I don't use regEx, it's going to be super long to check. Can someone help?

Comment: You can use _either_ dot notation _or_ bracket notation, not both. I also don’t think, this is going to work. What exactly are you even trying to check? Whether one of the keys is present? Whether all of the keys are present? Whether all of the keys in the regex are `true`?

Comment: Can you explain the case a bit more? Do you want to filter out all the items in the object with a key matching the regex?

Comment: I'd like to check if the preset object being passed to database has keys: abc, bcd, and so on. And the schema checks if the values for those keys are of type boolean.

Comment: `["abc", "bcd", "def", "efg"].every(a => preset.hasOwnProperty(a))` is probably what you want. A regex doesn’t help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check property's names by trying to access them by regexp object. You need to iterate over object property's and check their name.

```
for( var i in preset ) if( preset.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
    if( regEx.test.test( i ) ){
       var item = preset[i]
       //this is valid property name
       if( item.type === Boolean && item.optional === true ){ 
           // some other checks
       } else {
           //not boolean or not optional
       }
    } else {
       //this is not valid property name
    }
}
```